# Errors with apt package manager: unable to open directories for installation

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04, and i'm constantly getting errors where `sudo apt upgrade` malfunctions, and when i run `sudo apt install --fix-broken`, i get this output:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libreoffice-common
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 10 not to upgrade.
19 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/33.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 86.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 428397 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-common_1%3a6.2.3-0ubuntu0.19.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:6.2.3-0ubuntu0.19.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a6.2.3-0ubuntu0.19.04.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/share/libreoffice/share/config/images_helpimg.zip.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/share/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/program/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice': No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a6.2.3-0ubuntu0.19.04.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Have you made any changes to ownerships, permissions, or sudo?

Comment: Not to my knowledge

Comment: Your (your company's) virus scanner may block the installation of zipped files and immediately renaming them. For example[https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/1739991] sophos, but McAfee does it too. But, since this is already an old question, did you every find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check what permissions you are being given with sudo:

```
sudo -l
```

That should give you the lines:

```
User root may run the following commands on xyzzy:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

If you don't get that (don't have full permission), try running apt by naming root:

```
sudo -g root apt ...
```

If you do have full permission ... well, let's get specific.

I've had a look at my system, which has libreoffice and I don't have `/usr/share/libreoffice/share/config/images_helpimg.zip.dpkg-new`. Everything seems to work fine for me. Nevertheless, let's have a look at the directory:

```
ls -l -d /usr/share/libreoffice/share/config
```

The first part of that response is hopefully something like

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

If it isn't, I'll leave you to make it so, using chmod (`man chmod` will explain how to use it).

Then take a look at the files in the directory:

```
ls -l /usr/share/libreoffice/share/config
```

My system shows:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1337709 Jan 23 17:51 images_breeze.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3084230 Jan 23 17:51 images_galaxy.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2079435 Jan 23 17:51 images_oxygen.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7845910 Jan 23 17:51 images_tango.zip
```

The important part for you is that first permissions block. Everything should be read-write for root (rw-) and at least read for others (r--r--).

If that all turned out to be OK, then all I can think to suggest is to remove libreoffice and reinstall it. But first make sure your packages are up-to-date and I would also advise a complete upgrade, just to be sure. So,

```
apt update
apt upgrade
```

See if that has fixed your problems. If not:

```
apt remove libreoffice
```

If the troublesome files are still there (`ls -l /usr/share/libreoffice/share/config`), then follow that up with

```
apt autoremove
```

Then put libreoffice back again

```
apt install libreoffice
```

I'll keep my fingers crossed for you.

Comment: Tried what you advised, and it didn't work; instead, [I got this](https://pastebin.com/dZaHWTza)
(also, I'm unsure what the correct form of approach w. self-doxxing is on this platform, so I removed all usage of my computer's name and my PPAs just in case)

Comment: I was able to remove LibreOffice and all the broken dependencies of LibreOffice by using `sudo dpkg --purge --force-all [name]` , and listing all the broken dependancies ; whether or not this fixes the issue still needs to be seen

Comment: OK, I was trying not to take you into purge, without knowing how far you had got in setting up and using libreoffice. Still, hopefully, that will sort things for you. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, this fixes my issue temporarily, however, whenever I run `sudo apt upgrade` now, occasionally this exact same issue occurs with other packages, and the only way to get `dpkg` or `apt` working again is to force-purge the package and dependencies, *and not reinstall, as that suffers the exact same error*. So far, i have lost wine-staging, libreoffice and vscode this way. :-(

Comment: i found this [article](https://raphaelhertzog.com/2011/07/18/deciphering-one-of-dpkg-weirdest-errors-unable-to-open-pathtofoo-dpkg-new/), though i am unsure if it is relevant to this issue

Comment: I seem to be having a very similar problem. Not with LibreOffice (yet?) but with other (also mentioned) packages. Can't even uninstall/purge nodejs for instance because install is so botched up :/ The article tells me something, but doesn't really help solve the problem.

Comment: Aaaaah... silly me. It turns out my anti-virus software was apparently interfering with installation of various packages so when I disabled it's on access scan feature I was able to install all of the packages without a problem!